# How to measure accuracy for each target when some of the targets are NaNs in a TensorFlow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a dataset about 400 variables and 5 target columns. In many of the rows, only a few of the Y values are present, i.e. I have some unknown (NaNs) in the targets. I'm applying a custom loss function through TF to make sure that loss is only applied to predictions of Y values where there is a Y value to compare to.

```
def nan_friendly_loss(y_true, y_pred):
   y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.float32)
   y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, tf.float32)
   valids = tf.math.is_finite(
    y_true
   )
   #Only use y's that aren't NaN.
   y_true = y_true[valids] #tf.print(y_true)
   y_pred = y_pred[valids] #tf.print(y_pred)
   return = K.sum(K.square(y_pred-y_true))
```

For instance, If y_true is [1,2,Nan,NaN,5] and y_pred is [2,2,3,4,3], the loss would be 5 (1+0+0+0+4).

Now I'm trying to get a grasp on how well the model is performing on each of the targets. How can I make an accuracy function (mse for instance) so that, for each target Y, it skips the row when y_true is NaN when calculating average accuracies for the dataset? So far, the built in functions are just getting nan results, leading me to believe that it is unable to disregard NaN values in y_true. 
For example, the Ys below

```
y_true = [[1,2,Nan,NaN,5],[3,4,5,6,7]]  
y_pred = [[2,2,3,4,4],[3,4,3,5,5]],
```

should give the following result:

```
mse_accuracies == [0.5,0,4,1,2.5]
```

Comment: I didn't understand... your nan_friendly_loss doesn't work?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani, sorry about that! I had accidentally left my weight assignment for each of the Y values which is defined outside the function. It's removed now, so the function should work independently. Again, it solves a situation where some Y's are missing sometimes y_true = [1,5,3] or [2,NaN,NaN] or any other combination of NaNs and finites.

Comment: Any reason for not using the custom loss as custom metric too? Also the other way is to get the prediction from the model and later do the required processing

Comment: @Henrik - Did you try using custom loss as custom metric too and see if it answers your concern?

Answer (score 0):

When we need to use a loss function (or metric) other than the ones available , we can construct our own custom function and pass to `model.compile`.

So define the custom loss function as below. `nan_friendly_loss` is somewhat similar but you are defining `sum` instead of `mean` -

```
def custom_metric(y_true, y_pred):
   y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.float32)
   y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, tf.float32)
   valids = tf.math.is_finite(y_true)
   #Only use y's that aren't NaN.
   y_true = y_true[valids] #tf.print(y_true)
   y_pred = y_pred[valids] #tf.print(y_pred)
   return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true)
```

Modify your compile statement as below -

```
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss = nan_friendly_loss,
              metrics= custom_metric)
```

Now, your model's `custom_metric` will serve your requirement.

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @Henrik - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Tensorflow Warriors! I'm afraid this only whos the average of all the accuracies, not each of the targets' average accuracies. I'll clarify in the question.